# MsgBox not accepting optional parameters

Tags: vba, ms-word, optional-parameters, msgbox

I'm struggling with this basic piece of code :

```
     If Dir(LocationAddress & "\" & chart & " Complete.pdf") = "" Then
                MsgBox("The file wasn't created.", vbCritical + vbRetryCancel)
            Else
                MsgBox ("The file was created.")
            End If
```

When I click "save" in the VBA editor, the line corresponding to the error message turns red, and when I try to execute, it tells me there's a syntax error. I found this similar code online, with a different syntax, which also doesn't work, even when copied and pasted into the editor.

```
MsgBox("Important message", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "MsgBox Example")
```

I also ran my initial code with only one style instruction as an optional argument, to make sure the issue wasn't simply that I was combining them with improper syntax.

I hardly know anything about vba, I've only written a few subs by copying and editing code found online.

Comment: The use of (..) is telling the compiler that there should be an assignment to a variable, as sAns = MsgBox(....).  Remove the (..) and all will work.

Comment: Can you `Debug | Compile` without error? Is the error on the DIR command or Msgbox line? You should pull this `LocationAddress & "\" & chart & " Complete.pdf"` out and assign to a string variable so you can `debug.print` it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As igittr commented above, on the line `MsgBox("The file wasn't created.", vbCritical + vbRetryCancel)`, the parenthesis aren't needed.

When there's only one statement on the line, then VBA knows that the arguments are for the `MsgBox` procedure. If you put brackets around the arguments, it will try to evaluate everything within the brackets first, resulting in the error (that's why `MsgBox ("The file was created.")` still works, even though the brackets again aren't needed).

So either write the line as `MsgBox "The file wasn't created.", vbCritical + vbRetryCancel`

Or, if you want to still use brackets, use `Call MsgBox("The file wasn't created.", vbCritical + vbRetryCancel)`. This works because you have two statements, `Call` and `MsgBox`, and the brackets are needed to indicate what procedure the arguments belong to.

Comment: So `MsgBox ("The file was created.")` is a sub as there is no bracket after the function name. The single parameter is being passed by reference (or maybe by Value).

Answer (score 2):

Since, you show the message with some buttons option, the working solution should look as:

```
    Dim ans As VbMsgBoxResult
    ans = MsgBox("The file wasn't created.", vbCritical + vbRetryCancel, "A choice...")
      If ans <> vbRetry Then Exit Sub ' the code will stop even if the right corner 'x'  will be clicked.
      'your code if want it continuing...
      'or viceversa according to what do you intend doing in case of Cancel option.
```

Answer (score 1):

```
           MsgBox("The file wasn't created.", vbCritical + vbRetryCancel)
```

This won't work as you are calling a function as a sub. When calling functions as subs it needs to be treated as a sub which means no brackets. This is core Basic - brackets for functions and no brackets for subs.

```
            MsgBox ("The file was created.")
```

This will work because you aren't using brackets for the sub. Brackets around a parameter mean pass that parameter by value. Where ever possible computer languages pass by reference as it more efficient.

However it means that the string is copied, and the copy given to msgbox. So it uses more memory.

**Call**

`call` is obsolete. In QuickBasic it allowed a different calling convention when calling inline assembler functions. Assembler didn't return a value. So the convention was to pass a variable by reference as an input parameter and on return would hold the return value.

**Dir**

`Dir` is obsolete. It became obsolete in the 90s when it was replaced by the file system object. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/filesystemobject-object

**Brackets in Basic**

From https://ericlippert.com/2003/09/15/what-do-you-mean-cannot-use-parentheses/

The author was the maintainer programmer at Microsoft for VBScript.

> Here’s the deal: parentheses mean several different things in VB and
> hence in VBScript. They mean:
>
> 1. Define boundaries of a subexpression: Average = (First + Last) / 2
> 2. Dereference the index of an array: Item = MyArray(Index)
> 3. Call a function or subroutine: Limit = UBound(MyArray)
> 4. Pass an argument which would normally be byref as byval: in Result
>    = MyFunction(Arg1, (Arg2)) , Arg1 is passed by reference, Arg2is passed by value.
>
> That’s confusing enough already. Unfortunately, VB and hence VBScript
> has some weird rules about when #3 applies. The rules are
>
> 3.1) An argument list for a function call with an assignment to the returned value must be surrounded by parens: Result = MyFunc(MyArg)
>
> 3.2) An argument list for a subroutine call (or a function call with no assignment) that uses the Call keyword must be surrounded by
> parens: Call MySub(MyArg)
>
> 3.3) If 3.1 and 3.2 do not apply then the list must not be surrounded by parens.
>
> And finally there is the byref rule: arguments are passed by reference
> when possible but if there are “extra” parens around a variable then
> the variable is passed by value, not by reference.

**Trivia**

The `msgbox` function is a wrapper around the Windows `MessageBox()` functions. Basic passes on verbatim any parameters you pass. Of course only on Windows can you use the system parameters not listed in the Basic docs. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-messagebox